# react-native PullToRefreshViewAndroid warning

Tags: react-native

Android react-native version:0.16.1
npm react-native version:0.16.0

> Waring:Failed propType:Invalid prop 'colors[0]' of type 'number'
>   supplied to 'AndroidSwipeRefreshLayout', expected 'string'.Check the
>   render method of 'PullToRefreshViewAndroid'.

Comment: Any way you can paste  your code here? Thanks.

Comment: I run react-native PullToRefreshViewAndroid Demo @NaderDabit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is known but not solved yet apparantly.

For more informations see this thread in the react-native repo : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4663